# background image on several grids xaml windows phone

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, background, grid

I'm finalizing a windows phone application and the main menu is organized like this:

```
 <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
```

etc...
I would like to put a unique image background as a landscape of my 3 grids.

I have heard speaking about

```
<Grid.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="Images/background_top.png" AlignmentY="Top" AlignmentX="Center"/>
</Grid.Background>
```

But It seems working for only one grid, not for severals at the same time.

If Somebody know how to perform this landscape.

Thanks in Advance.
Florian SELVA

EDIT 1:

```
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

            <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
            <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,150,35,0" Width="328">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Name="Agni" Margin="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Source="/img/SMITE/Hindu/Agni/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="AhMuzenCab" Margin="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="/img/SMITE/Mayan/Ah Muzen Cab/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Anhur" Margin="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Source="/img/SMITE/Egyptian/Anhur/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Anubis" Margin="15" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Source="/img/SMITE/Egyptian/Anubis/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="AoKuang" Margin="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Source="/img/SMITE/Chinese/Ao Kuang/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Aphrodite" Margin="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Aphrodite/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Apollo" Margin="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Apollo/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Arachne" Margin="15" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Arachne/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Ares" Margin="15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Ares/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Artemis" Margin="15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Artemis/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Athena" Margin="15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Athena/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Bacchus" Margin="15" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="3" Source="/img/SMITE/Roman/Bacchus/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Bakasura" Margin="15" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="/img/SMITE/Hindu/Bakasura/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Cabrakan" Margin="15" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Source="/img/SMITE/Mayan/Cabrakan/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Bastet" Margin="15" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Source="/img/SMITE/Egyptian/Bastet/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Chaac" Margin="15" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="3" Source="/img/SMITE/Mayan/Chaac/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="ChangE" Margin="15" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Source="/img/SMITE/Chinese/Chang'e/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Chronos" Margin="15" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Chronos/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Cupid" Margin="15" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2" Source="/img/SMITE/Roman/Cupid/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Fenrir" Margin="15" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="3" Source="/img/SMITE/Norse/Fenrir/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Freya" Margin="15" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Source="/img/SMITE/Norse/Freya/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Geb" Margin="15" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Source="/img/SMITE/Egyptian/Geb/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="GuanYu" Margin="15" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" Source="/img/SMITE/Chinese/Guan Yu/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>
                <Image Name="Hades" Margin="15" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="3" Source="/img/SMITE/Greek/Hades/Icone.png" Tap="tap"></Image>

            </Grid>
```

This is one of the 3 grids.

Comment: Please post the actual XAML, this isn't enough to work with.

Comment: If you have 3 Grids then they must be wrapped in other Panel, set its Background then.

Comment: I'll edit my post with more code @WillemvanRumpt

Comment: @Maximus Do you mean creating a wrap pannel including the 3 grids?
Where should I place this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image over the whole page, set the background on the page level:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Background>
            <ImageBrush Stretch="Fill" ImageSource="Images/background_top.png" />
    </phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Background>
```

Comment: I have tried what you said but it changed nothing. I added this code after the <phone:PhoneApplicationPage   > was it the great place?

Comment: see my edit. It would help if you next time specify more clearly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't understandable, thought it was clear.
I wish I had a picture that scrolls across the three grids, revealing gradually as we scoll on the menu.